# Web scraping: how extract the text (names) in the hyperlinks in a web page?

Tags: html, r, hyperlink, web-scraping, text-extraction

I'm new in programming and R. please I need a little help. My petition is so simple (I know, I feel ashamed), for you will be so fast to resolve. I'm working in a project of invasive plant species and I need the list of names of plant species that is in this list: http://www.issg.org/database/species/List.asp

the names of the species are hyperlinks, how I can extract the names to a dataframe or table?

I've been extracting the links using this code below, but the text in the links doesn't have the names of the species :

```
url <- "http://www.issg.org/database/species/List.asp"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")
```

the links text is like this: 
First specie (e.g "`ecology.asp?si=1590&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN`")
 Second specie (e.g "`ecology.asp?si=1043&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN`") 
....

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just a minor, trivial really, modification of @jdharrison's excellent answer.

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.issg.org/database/species/List.asp"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- doc["//a[contains(@href,'ecology.asp?')]"]
df    <- data.frame(names=sapply(links,xmlValue))
head(df)
#                   names
# 1 Abelmoschus moschatus
# 2     Abrus precatorius
# 3       Acacia concinna
# 4        Acacia confusa
# 5     Acacia farnesiana
# 6     Acacia longifolia
```

So it turns out you do not need to use `xpathApply(...)`; you can "index" an `XMLInternalDocument` object using the XPath in `[...]`.

```
links <- doc["//a[contains(@href,'ecology.asp?')]"]
```

This generates a *list* of nodes which meet the XPath query condition. Then, you can "apply" the `xmlValue(...)` function to each element in the list using `sapply(...)`.

```
df    <- data.frame(names=sapply(links,xmlValue))
```

We use `sapply(...)` because we want a vector for the results, and warp that in a call to `data.frame(...)` to convert it to a data frame as you asked for.

Finally, I can't resist commenting on this business of "feeling ashamed" (although I'm sure I'll regret it...). Your question is well posed, concise, there is a code example, you provide your dataset (via the link), and you clearly state your desired result. Less than 1% of the questions I see on SO are like this, so you should feel the opposite of ashamed.

Comment: Very detailed explanation. So `doc["//a[contains(@href,'ecology.asp?')]"]` is essentially `getNodeSet` in disguise.

Comment: +1 is there a way to subscribe to your instructive posts @jlhoward :)

Comment: @jdharrison - Yes. About 3/4 of the way into the `getNodeSet(...)` documentation's (very extensive) examples, this method is identified as "syntactic sugar". I'm not aware of it being described anywhere else...

Comment: @Osssan - Not sure if this is what you meant, but if you click on anyone's name you get to a page that lists all the questions they've answered. I don't recommend this, though, as you'd be limiting yourself unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you and thanks to @jdharrison too. You guys saved my project :)

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the string `ecology.asp?` in your anchor tags then extract the element text and the href attribute

```
url <- "http://www.issg.org/database/species/List.asp"
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathApply(doc, "//a[contains(@href,'ecology.asp?')]"
                     , function(x){
                       data.frame(name = xmlValue(x), href = xmlGetAttr(x, "href"))
                     })
> head(do.call(rbind.data.frame, links))
name                                  href
1 Abelmoschus moschatus   ecology.asp?si=15&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
2     Abrus precatorius ecology.asp?si=1609&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
3       Acacia concinna ecology.asp?si=1343&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
4        Acacia confusa  ecology.asp?si=191&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
5     Acacia farnesiana   ecology.asp?si=49&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
6     Acacia longifolia ecology.asp?si=1662&fr=1&sts=&lang=EN
```